# Best thread to core ratio for hyperthreading processors

Tags: multithreading, performance, optimization, hyperthreading, cpu-cores

I did some research and I came to the conclusion that 1 thread per core is the best performing ratio, but the questions I read referred to very old cpus which had 2 cores and 2 threads. For a ryzen with 8 cores and 16 threads, should I summon 16 threads or 8 to get the best performance (assuming even and equal workloads)?

Comment: That's a bit simplistic - you should measure because it will be affected by I/O, memory pressure, cache sizes etc.

Comment: Using 1 thread per core is not always optimal. Sometimes you need more and sometimes less regarding the operations performed. Using 2 threads per core is good when your computation scale well but is *latency bound* (RAM/Cache or IOs). When the application does not scale, using less threads than available core is better (especially for IOs). On Ryzen it may be a good idea to use only a fraction of the cores due to *NUMA effects* (CCX). This strategy is used by some games as advised by AMD. So this is very complex in practice and the best is simply to test it...